# How to find the characteristic of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring of 27 elements $R$ = $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$ = {$a+bx+cx^2$ | $a,b,c < \Bbb{Z}_3$}. Where $x^3=x+2$.

How do I find the characteristic of this ring?

So I know that the characteristic of this ring is isn't 1 or zero. Do I just write all the elements out and find their inverses? How do the inverses help me figure out the characteristic though?

Comment: I think you try to mean $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$? If I am right, note that the characteristic of a ring is a positive integer $n$, such that $n.1=0$. Also see that, if $F$ is a ring with unity, then $F[x]$ and $F$ should have the same characteristic. Finally characteristic of $\Bbb{Z}_3$ is $3$.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha yes how do i type it like that I couldn't find it on the math jax page?

Comment: write \Bbb{Z}_3[x]

Comment: How many times can you add $1$ to itself before it becomes $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your definition of the characteristic. You can for example

1) Show that we have $\text{ker}(\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_3[x]) = 3\mathbb{Z}$, such that the characteristic of $R$ is $3$.

2) Compute the additive order of $1_{R}$, which will yield the same.

Answer (score 0):

The unit of $R$ is the unit of $\mathbb Z_3$ and so the characteristic of $R$ is the characteristic of $\mathbb Z_3$, which is $3$.